# Midpoints of Three Straight Lines are Collinear.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

> In quadrilateral $ABCD$, let $AB$ and $CD$ meet at $E$ and $AD$ and $BC$ meet at $F$. Then prove that the midpoints of $AC,BD$ and $EF$ are collinear.

**What I Tried**:- Here is a Picture :-

[image]

First extend $GH$ to meet $CE$ at $J$. Now I applied Menelaus Theorem on whatever triangles I found suitable :-

$$\rightarrow \frac{BI}{ID} * \frac{DJ}{CJ} * \frac{CL}{BL} = 1.$$
$$\rightarrow \frac{AK}{KD} * \frac{DJ}{CJ} * \frac{CH}{HA} = 1.$$
$$\rightarrow \frac{FG}{GE} * \frac{EJ}{CJ} * \frac{CL}{LF} = 1.$$
$$\rightarrow \frac{FG}{GE} * \frac{EJ}{DJ} * \frac{DK}{KF} = 1.$$

From here I got some results, like $\frac{AK}{KD} = \frac{CL}{BL}$ , but I do not know how to proceed further.

Can someone help me? Thank You.

Comment: See this - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3628106/midpoints-of-diagonals-of-a-quad-and-line-formed-by-points-formed-by-intersectio

Comment: You may want to read more on it on wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%E2%80%93Gauss_line:

Comment: Can someone reason me the downvotes??